How To Set QR Code Size Where Made With goqr.me API, In Spreadsheet Cell?
Since a week ago, I just realized that Google has announced Deprecation Policy a long time ago.  It seems today the service has actually been discontinued. I was quite annoyed because I was used to using this service to create QRcode, as in my question here.
For a replacement, I have used suggestions given by community members to switch to using the service goqr.me. With this alternative, it seems to be resolved.
But I'm still having problems arranging the layout of the QRcode results in cells in the Spreadsheet. In contrast to using the Google Chart service, where the QR Code results in cells can be set, with goqr.me I haven't found a way to set it.
I use this formula to create QR Code in Spreadsheet Cell :
=IMAGE("http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=SampleQrCde&size=100x100")
The result is like the following image:

There, the images are full in one cell, so that when printed they are stuck together and the scanning process is hampered.
With Google API's, in the previous process, images can be arranged with margin to the cell border, according to needs as follows:

Can anyone help solve this setup problem?

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about using the 2nd to 4th arguments of IMAGE function to use the custom image size? When this is used to your function =IMAGE("http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=SampleQrCde&size=100x100"), it becomes as follows.
Modified formula:
=IMAGE("http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=SampleQrCde&size=100x100", 4, 150, 150)

Testing:
When this is tested, the following result is obtained. In this case, the width and the height of cell "B3" are 200 and 200 pixels, respectively. And, the image size is fixed at 150 x 150.

Note:

Please adjust the custom image size to your actual situation.

Reference:

IMAGE


Sorry for my poor English. Thanks @Tanaike.  It's work.

Thanks for your suggestion reference to set IMAGE too.

@PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
